# How do you fill a text field based on dynamically generated links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The gist of it is that I have a dynamically generated drop down based off an array in JQuery. I have a text field next to it that should output an answer based on what was selected in the array.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Vendor Contacts
        <ul class="vendor_list">    
        </ul>
    </li>
    <input id="vendor_contact" type="text" />
</ul>
```

This is the HTML that I set up and here's the Javascript:

```
var vendors = ['vendor1, vendor2, vendor3'];
var contact_info = ['email1','email2','email3']

var vList = $('ul.vendor_list');
$.each(vendors, function (i) 
{
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('menu_item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .appendTo(vList);
    var aaa = $('<a/>') 
        .addClass('vendors')
        .text(vendors[i])
        .appendTo(li);
});
```

What I think is the next step is:

```
$("#vendor_list").on('click', '.vendors', function () {
    $("vendor_contact")val($(contact_info[i]))
```

Needless to say, I mind's pretty warped around this one. I'm starting to get into jQuery and just want to see how I can fill the text box in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have missing quotation marks in your `vendors` array:

```
var vendors = ['vendor1', 'vendor2', 'vendor3'];
```

Next, you should use `class` selector, not `id` on your `.vendor_list` element:

```
$(".vendor_list").on('click', '.vendors', function () {
    // ...
```

Next, missing `#` sign, as you're selecting the element by its `id`:

```
$("#vendor_contact")val(//...
```

(by `$("vendor_contact")` you're trying to select a not existing tag `<vendor_contact>`)

Last thing, use something like `data` attribute to determine the actual selection:

```
$.each(vendors, function(i){
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('menu_item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .appendTo(vList);
    var aaa = $('<a/>') 
        .addClass('vendors')
        .text(vendors[i])
        // add 'data-id' attr:
        .data('id', i)
        .appendTo(li);
});
```

final JS:

```
$(".vendor_list").on('click', '.vendors', function () {
    $("#vendor_contact").val(contact_info[$(this).data('id')]);
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/69pgj780/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! This worked wonderfully! And I see that I have a lot more to learn. Thanks for helping me continue to get better at this. You're awesome!